# Join tables even if don't exist on other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables and want to join but if row is not existing in other table results are not shown.

```
+-------------------+   +-------------------+   
|      TABLE 1|     |   |     Table 2       |
+-------------------+   +-------------------+   
|deviceID|  xxx     |   |deviceID|    yyy   |   
|-------------------|   |-------------------|   
| 1    |  Service 1 |   | 1    |   Asset 1  | 
| 2    |  Service 2 |   | 2    |   Asset 2  |   
| 3    |  Service 3 |   |      |   
+-------------------+   +-------------------+
```

SQL:

```
SELECT L.xxx, A.yyy from TABLE1 L JOIN TABLE2 A on L.deviceID=A.deviceID
```

The results are shown are deviceID:1,2 and 3 is not showing, I want to show it even if it doesn't exist on table2

I have tried **LEFT JOIN** and **RIGHT JOIN** but is not working

Answer (score 1):

Did you try a simple `left join`?

```
SELECT L.xxx, A.yyy
FROM TABLE1 L LEFT JOIN
     TABLE2 A 
     ON L.deviceID = A.deviceID;
```

This should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As this example shows, LEFT JOIN works just fine. For you.

So that doesn't seems to be the problem. cam you provide an dbfoddle example whre it doesn't work

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE Table2 (
  `deviceID` INTEGER,
  `yyy` VARCHAR(7)
);

INSERT INTO Table2
  (`deviceID`, `yyy`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'Asset 1'),
  ('2', 'Asset 2');

CREATE TABLE Table1 (
  `deviceID` INTEGER,
  `xxx` VARCHAR(9)
);

INSERT INTO Table1
  (`deviceID`, `xxx`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'Service 1'),
  ('2', 'Service 2'),
  ('3', 'Service 3');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT
t1.deviceID
,t1.xxx
,t2.yyy
FROM
Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
Table2 t2 ON t1.deviceID = t2.deviceID;
```

---

```
| deviceID | xxx       | yyy     |
| -------- | --------- | ------- |
| 1        | Service 1 | Asset 1 |
| 2        | Service 2 | Asset 2 |
| 3        | Service 3 |         |
```

**Query #2**

```
SELECT

t1.xxx
,t2.yyy
FROM
Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
Table2 t2 ON t1.deviceID = t2.deviceID;
```

---

```
| xxx       | yyy     |
| --------- | ------- |
| Service 1 | Asset 1 |
| Service 2 | Asset 2 |
| Service 3 |         |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ihwaUZpdhBvd4vhTqQAVsG/0)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `INNER JOIN`?

```
SELECT L.xxx, A.yyy
FROM TABLE1 L INNER JOIN
     TABLE2 A 
     ON L.deviceID = A.deviceID;
```

> This should work because `INNER JOIN`  takes the common values in both tables;
> [image: Inner Join Diagram]

***OUTPUT***

```
| DeviceID |    xxx    |    yyy   |
|:--------:|:---------:|:--------:|
|     1    | Service 1 | Assest 1 |
|     2    | Service 2 | Assest 2 |
```